# Axial tilt of a planet with weeklong nights

Tags: climate, axial-tilt

Say we have a planet that takes 8 Earth days to fully rotate on the axis. At a latitude of 45 degrees, during the winter solstice, its day lasts 1 Earth day, or 24 hours, and its night lasts 7 Earth days, or 1 week. What axial tilt will result in a day length of 1/8 of the axial rotation at an latitude of 45 degrees?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**43-44 degrees**

Looking at Earth, even when you get to a latitude of 60 degrees there are still about [five and a half hours of daylight](https://www.orchidculture.com/COD/daylength.html#60S) (ie almost a quarter of the day length).  In order to get the daylight length down to 1/8 of the rotation period, it is necessary to be within a degree or so of the Arctic/Antarctic Circle.  Which puts the Arctic/Antarctic circles at 46-47 degrees north and south respectively, with a corresponding tilt of 43-44 degrees.

Exactly how close depends on the definition of "daylight" - does the sun need to be above the horizon for the entire 1/8 of the rotation or does a period of pre-dawn/dusk light count?  Is there a mountain range immediately to the north/south as applicable that will block low-angle sunlight?

Note that this puts the tropics within 2-4 degrees of the arctic/antarctic circle!  It may be worth looking at the answers to [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/110254/would-the-tropic-and-arctic-climate-bands-switch-if-the-earths-axial-tilt-chang?rq=1) question about a planet with an axial tilt of 60 degrees to consider the impacts on your proposed planet's environment, even though it is not quite as extreme.

Comment: I appreciate the acceptance, but generally it is best to wait 24 hours before accepting an answer.  This gives an opportunity for people to comment on my answer - it's possible that I have made a mistake - or for someone to provide a better answer.  With people on this site from all over the world, we need to allow for all timezones.

Comment: The green checkmark tyranny must be culled in the root. The users could vote on a meta to have the rule implemented by the system. If not a full block, at least a warning to the OP stating that they should wait for more answers.